# Different meaning of 何?

Tags: word-choice, words

While reading some lyrics online, I stumbled upon the following phrase:

> これ以上何を失えば 心は許されるの

Which I could myself losely translate as following:

> If I lose ***what*** more (than I already have), will my heart be forgiven?

And this is a translation I found on the internet:

> If I lose any more than this, will my heart be forgiven

Now I'm wondering why これ以上何 means "Any more than this" rather than "What more than this"

Thanks

Comment: Hi. I might try and make an answer when I have some more time, but upon asking a few friends, it seems that the lyrics are pretty confusing in meaning, even to my Japanese friends (see comments to answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their translation is wrong. Yours is accurate.

> If I lose what more (than I already have), will my heart be forgiven?

= My heart will be forgiven if I lose what? (on top of what I already lost)

= What else must I lose for my heart to be forgiven?

(As an aside, I'm not sure whether or not "heart being forgiven" is the best interpretation for the second part... it seems like it could have some other possible meanings, e.g. related to [心を許す](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BF%83%E3%82%92%E8%A8%B1%E3%81%99)? ...Not sure)

Comment: No offense, but i think an accurate answer to this question would be better formed by understanding the whole sentence. (I don't understand it myself)

Comment: I don't think the second half's meaning impacts the understanding of the grammar, but yes -- a better answer could be written by someone who had that understanding >_<  Sorry this is all I could manage. (However, it's part of a song (the first line), so I'm not even sure that its meaning is unambiguous in the first place. [Here's a link to lyrics](http://homepage2.nifty.com/marua-S/d-hanabi.htm) if anyone wants to look for more context.)

Comment: Also isn't "If I lose any more than this" a more accurate translation than "If I lose what more (than I already have)" ? I think 何 can be sometimes translated as "any" - for instance 何かあるの- "what's up/ anything wrong?" ...「それで今手がけているものは何かあるのかね？」-
"And have you any on hand just now?"

Comment: Both of those example sentences have 何 followed by か, which creates the meaning "any". If the original sentence had 何か, the translation in the question would be correct, certainly.

Comment: I see. Well, in the same way, where do you get the meaning of "must" from? - perhaps we are debating semantics but your final translation seems to be somewhat unfaithful as well.

Comment: I hesitated about putting "must" in for the same reason, but I don't see another way. The most literal translation that's grammatical in English is the translation (I'll call it "2") immediately below my quote block, but it is unnatural. I think, despite the appearance of the word "must", the final translation(3) is as close as you can get to the 2nd translation in natural English. For instance, "What 'will' I lose before my heart is forgiven"(4) doesn't work; translations 1 and 2 ask about consequences of possible events, whereas (4) says that events WILL actually happen.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, if we have P(x)=I lose x, and Q=My heart will be forgiven, then the question is asking for the 'x' that satisfies "P(x) implies Q". ...I think the jump from "What x will satisfy this equation?" to "What x MUST I put in to satisfy this equation?" is not a big semantic jump, and justifies the word.

Comment: @yadokari, I fully agree with Hyperworm's analysis. Japanese allows question words in dependent clauses, but in English the rules for wh-extraction from dependent clauses are more complicated. You might be able to get away with "What will my heart be forgiven if I lose (on top of what I already lost)", but it sounds rather awkward, and it's not easy to see where the "what" was extracted from.

Comment: @dainichi, what is your thoughts on which is the most accurate and natural translation?

Comment: I asked japanese friends and after consulting I came up with this very figurative translation: "What else must I do to find peace in my heart" . I am thinking 許される means "be pardoned by the universe/god" which I take to mean "have my burden lifted". I take 失えば "if I lose" as meaning not "losing" but more like "getting rid of" as in losing negative burdens- so he is saying (I guess) = "If I lose more negativity than this, will my burden be lifted? "....But that is just my best guess so far.

Comment: Well the general consensus seems to be this isn't a straightforward thing, even in Japanese. Thanks alot for the responses everyone! They were very helpful :)

Comment: @yadokari, Hyperworm's "What else must I lose for my heart to be forgiven" seems like the best translation to me, since it's an accurate translation and natural English. Of course, this is poetry, so as long as you're willing to relax the accuracy constraint, "best" can be highly subjective.

Comment: @yadokari: I second Hyperworm and dainichi.  I think that you are trying to find out what it means for a heart to be forgiven.  There are probably many interpretations, as is usual for poetic text, but I do not think that it is the point of the question.